# A multimap with good performance

Tags: java, performance, multimap

In my code I have a map that is used heavily, several thousand times in a few seconds. Originally I had a TreeMap, but when testing with 9,000 entries I watched my old processor melt. And this needs to scale. So I moved to a HashMap and performance was excellent.

Now I am changing my design and am looking for a MultiMap. However I'm afraid of the performance impact on the `get()` side, as it must iterate over said large map picking out the matching keys, and when called many many times even synchronized it seems like it would be slow.

Is there a good MultiMap that can handle such large values with great performance? Performance is critical in this application, as there could be many large separate maps handling a very large workload, making "small" performance losses very big issues.

Bonus points if it can be extracted to work alone without any dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure about performance numbers, but it seems that you might be able to quickly benchmark the different implementations that are available? The most common libraries would be the commons-collections from Apache and then the Google Guava library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one that was recommended to me in one of my questions was the Apache Commons MultiMap:
http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html

It's free software, so you can at least get the source to look at it, and depending on your license situation, you can modify it or use it standalone.

It uses an ArrayList internally, but I imagine you can probably change it to use a HashSet or something.  I would look at the `createCollection(Collection coll)` method.

UPDATE: Actually, Guava's HashMultiMap appears to already be what I was talking about:
https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.java

I looked at the source and it seems that each collection of values is in fact backed by a HashSet.

Comment: Seems to of been depreciated in favor of `MultiValueMap`. But I'm still not sure if the performance, iterating over this large of a collection for each call looks a little expensive

Comment: Seems that you're right.  I updated my post because I found something else.

Answer (score 2):

I had a requirement where I had to have a `Map<Comparable, Set<Comparable>>` where insertion on the Map be concurrent and also on the corresponding Set, but once a Key was consumed from the Map, it had to be deleted, think if as a Job running every two seconds which is consuming the whole `Set<Comparable>` from an specific Key but insertion be totally concurrent so that most values be buffered when the Job kicks in, here is my implementation:

**Note:** I use Guava's helper class Maps to create the concurrent Maps, also, this solution emulates ***Java concurrency in Practice Listing 5.19***:

```
import com.google.common.collect.MapMaker;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: gmedina
 * Date: 18-Sep-2012
 * Time: 09:17:50
 */
public class LockMap<K extends Comparable>
{
  private final ConcurrentMap<K, Object> locks;

  public LockMap()
  {
    this(16, 64);
  }

  public LockMap(final int concurrencyLevel)
  {
    this(concurrencyLevel, 64);
  }

  public LockMap(final int concurrencyLevel, final int initialCapacity)
  {
    locks=new MapMaker().concurrencyLevel(concurrencyLevel).initialCapacity(initialCapacity).weakValues().makeMap();
  }

  public Object getLock(final K key)
  {
    final Object object=new Object();
    Object lock=locks.putIfAbsent(key, object);
    return lock == null ? object : lock;
  }

}


import com.google.common.collect.MapMaker;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

/**
 * A general purpose Multimap implementation for delayed processing and concurrent insertion/deletes.
 *
 * @param <K> A comparable Key
 * @param <V> A comparable Value
 */
public class ConcurrentMultiMap<K extends Comparable, V extends Comparable>
{
  private final int initialCapacity;
  private final LockMap<K> locks;
  private final ConcurrentMap<K, Set<V>> cache;

  public ConcurrentMultiMap()
  {
    this(16, 64);
  }

  public ConcurrentMultiMap(final int concurrencyLevel)
  {
    this(concurrencyLevel, 64);
  }

  public ConcurrentMultiMap(final int concurrencyLevel, final int initialCapacity)
  {
    this.initialCapacity=initialCapacity;
    cache=new MapMaker().concurrencyLevel(concurrencyLevel).initialCapacity(initialCapacity).makeMap();
    locks=new LockMap<K>(concurrencyLevel, initialCapacity);
  }

  public void put(final K key, final V value)
  {
    synchronized(locks.getLock(key)){
      Set<V> set=cache.get(key);
      if(set == null){
        set=Sets.newHashSetWithExpectedSize(initialCapacity);
        cache.put(key, set);
      }
      set.add(value);
    }
  }

  public void putAll(final K key, final Collection<V> values)
  {
    synchronized(locks.getLock(key)){
      Set<V> set=cache.get(key);
      if(set == null){
        set=Sets.newHashSetWithExpectedSize(initialCapacity);
        cache.put(key, set);
      }
      set.addAll(values);
    }
  }

  public Set<V> remove(final K key)
  {
    synchronized(locks.getLock(key)){
      return cache.remove(key);
    }
  }

  public Set<K> getKeySet()
  {
    return cache.keySet();
  }

  public int size()
  {
    return cache.size();
  }

}
```

Comment: Just for security...can you change this account's email address to the one used here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1663066 then @reply me. Thanks

Comment: Done, if that doesn't match let me know, I have two email address I could had used.

Answer (score 1):

The choice would largely depend on what you want to do. There are many data-structures and some are better than others in specific areas and vice versa.

I could recommend you potential candidates. If it is entirely read, ImmutableMultiMap might be a good fit.

If you need **concurrent** read/write, then I'd implement my own multimap, perhaps using ConcurrentHashMap and ConcurrentSkipListSet (you need to be careful because the semantics between a synchronized multimap and a multipmap created this way using non-blocking data structures differ).  If you use ConcurrentSkipListSet, you can then use binary search and it's faster than just iterating.

If you have a lot of rows, you could also start by just using a ConcurrentHashMap and a synchronized list. That could significantly reduce the contention, which might be enough to resolve your performance problem and it's simple.

Comment: How would one use binary search on a ConcurrentSkipListSet? I can't find an answer to this anywhere, or maybe I'm just overlooking something...

Comment: @Pepijin: It was probably wrong to call it "binary search", but what happens is quite similar to it: http://igoro.com/archive/skip-lists-are-fascinating/

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Google Guava as a replacement to Apache Commons whenever possible... Here's an example with its Multimap's implementation HashMultiMap, and notice that the values of the map is a collection of the values instead of a single reference. The method "contains()" is used for the result of get(key).

```
private Multimap<Phase, ResultingState> phaseResults = HashMultimap.create();

/**
 * @param withState is the state to be verified.
 * @param onPhase is the phase to be verified.
 * @return Whether the given result was reported in the given phase.
 */
public boolean wasReported(ResultingState withState, Phase onPhase) {
    return phaseResults.containsKey(onPhase) && phaseResults.get(onPhase).contains(withState);
}

/**
 * @param resultingState is the resulting state.
 * @return Whether the given resulting state has ever been reported.
 */
public boolean anyReported(ResultingState resultingState) {
    return phaseResults.values().contains(resultingState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you mention that you "iterate over said large map picking out the matching keys", that makes me wonder whether you're using the best data structure. Is there a way you could avoid that iteration?

Note that Guava includes multiple multimap implementations with different performance characteristics. As Zwei mentioned, an ImmutableMultimap has better performance than the mutable multimaps. The SetMultimaps are faster if your code checks whether the multimap contains a particular value; otherwise an ArrayListMultimap performs better.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom Many to Many relationship map based on HashSets and HashMaps. And the reason I needed one with good performance is that I would be iterating over the whole map to compare a given string to a string in the object.